# FTP: Why use IP of PASV response at all?

Tags: ftp, protocols, ipv4

When sending the FTP command "PASV", the FTP server responds with information on which host and port a data connection can be established.

This host information can be problematic if there is a NAT involved. Some clients resolve this by comparing the IP of the proposed data connection host with the one from the control connection: If the one proposed after PASV is a local one while the control connection is not using a local one, only the ports given by the PASV response are used while using the IP of the host connection.

As an example, see the Apache Commons implementation: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/net/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.java?revision=1788985&view=markup#l3876

My question is now: Why use the host of the PASV answer at all? Why not just always only use the ports of the PASV answer but use the host of the control connection? As far as I know this is how it's done with IPv6 but I never see it with IPv4. Why?

Comment: You're dealing with an absolutely ancient protocol that nobody should still be using. The world just looked a bit different when FTP was invented, but it hasn't been relevant in over a decade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time FTP was designed there were enough IP addresses and NAT was not a thing to be considered. But FTP was designed to support a use case where a client initiated a transfer between two different systems - see figure 2 in [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) or read about [File eXchange Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) for details. And for this use case it was necessary that the IP addresses in the PORT or PASV command could be different from the (single) server resp. client IP.

> As far as I know this is how it's done with IPv6 but I never see it with IPv4.

You are probably referring to the EPRT and EPSV commands which only take a port number and no IP address. While these commands were introduced since the original PORT and PASV commands did not support IPv4 these command can be used for both IPv6 and IPv4 and several clients use these for IPv4 too, thereby avoiding the problems with the wrong IP address in PORT/PASV.

Comment: Thanks! I read the FXP link but even here PASV returns the same IP as the control connection that was asked to provide it. PASV is like asking a server to provide a connection – this server will then always use its own IP (if it follows the standard). PORT is like telling a server about a connection – instead of providing such a connection, the client could indeed use the connection provided by a preceding PASV command to another server. Still, I fail to see why I – from a client perspective – shouldn't just ignore the IP part of the answer after PASV.

Comment: @Pat: PASV and PORT are modeled the same way, i.e. the client might instruct the server to connect to a different system then the client with PORT and the server might instruct the client to connect to a different system with PASV. Still, for almost all practical purposes the IP address could be ignored today. That still does not mean that it will work then since with NAT not only the IP might change but also the port (although less likely).

Comment: The weird thing is that this behaviour is totally different when using EPSV with IPv6. There, clients don't use the host in the EPSV response. So this "feature" is probably just not really used anymore.

Comment: The question is what does "almost all practical purposes" mean. I'm going to mark this answer as correct but to be honest, I'm still considering to ignore host information in a PASV response. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pat: *"...The question is what does "almost all practical purposes" mean"* - the FXP feature is normally not used. But given how old and widespread FTP is I'm pretty sure that somewhere is some mostly forgotten but still critical system that relies on it. The nice thing with EPRT/EPSV is that you can be sure that nobody uses such FXP feature with IPv6 simply because it was never possible.